# Xcode. Хранение элементов массива в пользовательском классе

Tags: objective-c, ios, классы

Как для элементов массива в контроллере создать пользовательский класс который будет хранить в себе имя (NSString), координаты (CLLocation) и ссылку (NSURL)?

Answer (score 1):

как то так:

```
MyClass.h

@interface MyClass : NSObject  {
 }

@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation* location;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL* url;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* name;

@end

MyClass.m

@implementation MyClass
@synthesize location, url, name;

- (id)init {
self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
    //
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```